# scaling the input features with respect to another input variable in python

Tags: python, scaling

I am working with the GPS dataset of the athletes and football players.

I have 6 Input/predictor variables, among which 3 variables are dependant on the "time_played" input variable. These 3 variables are going to change if the time_played is changed.

```
reproducible code:

df = {'player id' : ['1','2' ,'3','4'],     #categorical
  'position' : ['1','2' ,'3','4'],          #categorical
  'time_played': ['50','90' ,'88','70'],
  'distance': ['5117','11520' ,'10865','8652'],
  'acc_events' : ['2','4' ,'8','8'],
  'dec_events' : ['8','11' ,'14','9'],
  'energy' : ['29157','49520' ,'47865','39552'] }

Objective: 

Predicting the energy for each player for 90 mins.
```

I need to scale all those time-dependent variables(distance, acc_event and dec_event) to 90 minutes. Once I scale these variables to 90 minutes, I would be able to predict the output variable(energy) also for 90 minutes for these newly scaled variables.

As I have 2 categorical variables here, 'player id' and 'position', I don't think using the min-max normalization method is going to give me an efficient result.

```
x_normalised = [ { x - min(x) } / { max(x) - min(x) } ] * 90
```

Is there any way I could scale these time_dependant input variables to 90 mins and then I could use the scaled values to predict the output/energy?

Any suggestion/help would be highly helpful. 
TIA.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by scaling them to 90 minutes. but don't you just need to divide them by `time_played` in order to get e.g. distance per minute?

Comment: Yes, I can do energy/time_played to get the energy for per minute and then multiply by 90 to get the energy for 90minutes. But the accuracy is not good. So, I am trying to predict the energy(using linear regression) for each player if he has played for 90 minutes. Moreover, all the players don't play for full 90 minutes, so to have a uniform time frame, I need to calculate energy for 90 minutes by calculating the other time-dependent input features also for 90 minutes.